# Finding elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting to code an extension and I've encountered a problem. I'm using "getElementById" to see if this is the correct webpage. And I'm always no matter what the same result "null". Can someone help me, please? Here is the code:

```
var abc = document.getElementById('questionText');
console.log(abc);
if (abc == null) {
    alert("not working");
} else {
    alert("works");
}
```

Comment: What browser is this extension for? Which script is this code in (background, content, popup, etc.)?

Comment: And when in the page lifecycle do you run this? Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code inside DOMReady, otherwise you might end up looking for the element before HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var abc = document.getElementById('questionText');
  console.log(abc);
  if (abc == null) {
    alert("not working");
  } else {
    alert("works");
  }
});
```